# How does Jupyter find modules?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue where my Jupyter Notebook can't find an installed module, and I'm surprised that I can't find this basic information anywhere in the documentation. How do I specify where any given instance of Jupyter Notebook should look for modules?

A possibly related question: When I use `jupyter --path`, I see a listing of directories under the "data" heading. Is this where Jupyter looks for modules, and if so, what file do I edit to change it?

**Edit** I'm starting to understand, and I think I asked the wrong question.  Jupyter loads a Python interpreter, and the interpreter is what deals with modules.  How a Python interpreter finds modules is well-covered territory, but I still don't understand the first part.  So, I should have asked, "How does Jupyter determine which Python executable to use?"

Comment: If you are using anaconda, everything jupyter is using is from the python distribution you installed using anaconda. Even if it's not, jupyter is using the default python distribution on your machine. Check if you installed the package to the correct python distribution first.

Comment: @YilunZhang I am using the Jupyter that was installed by Anaconda, and your comment helps me understand the problem. How can I change which Python executable Jupyter uses?

Comment: Depending on the device you are using, the setup is different. For Mac, after anaconda installation, it should be added to your path automatically, in windows, you will probably need to add it to your path environment variable manually. There are lots of example tutorials online that you can follow to do this.